# Null value in column primary_id when a spring boot session is created

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session

I have been trying to add session data to my application. For most part I have been following the docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-jdbc-boot.html) for creating a jdbc http session. Accordingly, I have

HttpSessionConfig.java

```
@EnableJdbcHttpSession 
public class HttpSessionConfig {}
```

and I have my username,password, database name and so forth in my application.properties file. Furthermore, I created the session tables using the script found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-postgresql.sql). However, I go to my login page I get the error

```
PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO SPRING_SESSION(SESSION_ID, 
CREATION_TIME, LAST_ACCESS_TIME, MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL, 
PRINCIPAL_NAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; ERROR: null value in column 
"primary_id" violates not-null constraint Detail: Failing row contains 
(null, 835a7b12-d171-4f77-bd22-7da7ed78ca12, 1510171280672, 
1510171280672, 1800, null, null).; nested exception is 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column 
"primary_id" violates not-null constraint Detail: Failing row contains 
(null, 835a7b12-d171-4f77-bd22-7da7ed78ca12, 1510171280672, 
1510171280672, 1800, null, null).
```

However, as far I can tell from the docs this is suppose to work. Is there a step that I overlooked or isn't in the docs?

Comment: Which database are you using? Are you setting a value for "spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy" in your application.properties|yml file? If you create an example project in GitHub,, that would help me and others look over what is wrong.

Comment: @Pytry I am using postgres and I have no physical-strategy value set. I will try to create a minimal project over the next 20 minutes or so.

Comment: @Pytry I think I figured out the issue. Namely, I used the postgres-schema.sql file found in the boot-spring example and it worked which is different than the one grabbed from the repo and this worked correctly.

Comment: Well that's good to hear:)

Comment: I just wanted to clarify what the issue/solution was for people that come across the same issue. The issue turned out be that I was using at time the 1.3 version of spring session, but was I generated the 2.0.0 schema which will produce the above error.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was as @user5960886 pointed in one of their own replies.

I was using the wrong schema (master) for the spring table `spring_session` (and `spring_session_attributes`) which requires `prinary_id` to not be null where my application was running and populating the schema that does not populate this column (namely 1.3.0.RELEASE). 
Here are the links that have the 2 schemas:

Version 1.3.0.RELEASE
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-session/src/main/resources/org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-postgresql.sql

Latest Master
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-jdbc/src/main/resources/org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-postgresql.sql

You may need to drop and recreate your existing tables if you have created them using the latest schema. NOTE: Existing data will be lost. Here is the drop SQL statements you can use:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-projects/spring-session/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-session/src/main/resources/org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-drop-postgresql.sql